# How to import es2020 function for jest testing | typescript, nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, ts-jest

I am new with jest testing and I want to import a function from another file that should be tested. I am writing my code with typescript and it will be exceuted on a node.js server.

```js
//  ../src/services/misc.ts
export const getIpAdress = () => {
  return '192.168.0.52';
};
```

Without the import in `calc.test.ts` and without the last describe call in `calc.test.ts` the test will run and every test passes. How is this fixable??

If i ran the test just as it stands here, the test will fail.

```js
//  tests/calc.test.ts
import { getIpAdress } from '../src/services/misc';

const add = (x: number, y: number) => {
  return x + y;
};

describe('test add function', () => {
  it('should return 15 for add(10,5)', () => {
    expect(add(10, 5)).toBe(15);
  });
});

describe('test IpAdress function', () => {
  it('should return ip adress', () => {
    expect(getIpAdress()).toBe('192.168.0.52');
  });
});
```

Fail Message if i execute the test with `npm run test`

```
> ticketing@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  dist/tests/calc.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such 
syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Users\joshua\Documents\Business\Ticketing\ticketing\dist\tests\calc.test.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { getIpAdress } from '../src/services/misc';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1422:14)

 FAIL  tests/calc.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/services/misc.ts:4:34 - error TS1343: The 'import.meta' meta-property is only allowed when the '--module' option is 'es2020', 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext'.

    4 const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 2 failed, 2 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.912 s
Ran all test suites.
```

My `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    // "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

my `jest.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
export default {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

my `package.json`

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "ticketing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Ticketing System to sell Tickets for events online and manage these",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/app.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "scriptsComments": {
    "tsc": "Builds all the javascript(js) files from the typescript(ts) files."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://git@gitlab.com/cl/ticketing.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/cl/ticketing/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/cl/ticketing#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "@types/pdfkit": "^0.12.7",
    "@types/qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cross-fetch": "^3.1.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mariadb": "^3.0.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.8.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.13.0",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.1",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.23",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.38.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.38.0",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like Jest doesn't like ESM. You'll have to either use CommonJS in your tests or compile your tests to CommonJS.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it by setting my project to commonjs and also the compileroptions. I forked a nodejs typescript jest Boilerplate project from github and started to figure out how it worked in the repository and used the knowledge for my repository.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
changed this here:

```js
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.ts', '!**/*.d.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/dist/']
};
```

```json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    // "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

I can now import all my modules and also the node_modules from the *.test.ts files.